# iOS 15 DualSense is opening App Library on PS button long press

Tags: ios, swift, ios15

On iOS 15 a long press on the PS Button of the DualSense controller is opening the App Library and I don't receive a callback via the valueChangedHandler function. The App library which will be opened looks like this [image: AppLibrary]

This is how I handle all controller inputs:

```
func handleController(controller: GCController) {
    controller.extendedGamepad?.valueChangedHandler = { [weak self] (gamepad: GCExtendedGamepad, element: GCControllerElement) in
        guard let self = self else {
            return
        }
        // no feedback received when performing a long press on the PS button
}
```

Can the game library be suppressed somehow? Sony's PS Remote Play app somehow manages to suppress it, but I don't know how, nor can I find anything in Apple's official API documentation.

Edit: Seems this problem only occurs on iPads, on iPhones this problem doesn't exist. Is there some API or anything on iPads to suppress this behaviour? I assume the most majority of users don't want to open the App Library in the middle of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone ever faces the same problem you can actually disable system gestures for the Home button.

In Swift all you have to add is this line (controller is a *GCController* object)

```
controller.physicalInputProfile.buttons[GCInputButtonHome]?.preferredSystemGestureState = .disabled
```

In ObjectiveC it would work like this

```
controller.physicalInputProfile.buttons[GCInputButtonHome].preferredSystemGestureState = GCSystemGestureStateDisabled;
```

Thanks to the Apple employee who helped me here

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711905

Edit: on tvOS this isn't working as the PS button (menu button) of a controller always have to act as home event

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/715012